# Upload a streamable in-memory document (.docx) to FTP with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, spire.doc

I am trying to upload a .docx file which is in `MemoryStream` to FTP

But when upload is completed, the file is empty.

```
MemoryStream mms = new MemoryStream();
document2.SaveToStream(mms, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);

string ftpAddress = "example";
string username = "example";
string password = "example";

using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(mms))
{
    // adnu is a random file name.
    WebRequest request =
        WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress + "/public_html/b/" + adnu + ".docx");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the document directly to the request stream. There's no point using an intermediate `MemoryStream`. And `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` are for working with text files, while a `.docx` is a binary file format, so do not use those either.

```
WebRequest request =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/document.docx");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    document2.SaveToStream(ftpStream, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);
}
```

Or use [`WebClient.OpenWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openwrite):

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    const string url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/document.docx";
    using (Stream uploadStream = client.OpenWrite(url))
    {
        document2.SaveToStream(uploadStream, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);
    }
}
```

---

You will only need an intermediate `MemoryStream`, if the Spire library requires a seekable stream, what the `Stream` returned by `FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` is not. I cannot test that.

If that's the case, use:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
document2.SaveToStream(memoryStream, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);

memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

WebRequest request =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/document.docx");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    memoryStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
}
```

Or again, you can use `WebClient.OpenWrite` as in the previous example.

See also a similar question [Zip a directory and upload to FTP server without saving the .zip file locally in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46682983/850848).