# Create Excel file directly on FTP with C# using EPPlus library

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ftp, epplus

I want to create an Excel file on FTP server. I've tried creating a file locally and it works so to the problem: How do I create it in FTP instead of local drive?

```
ExcelPkg.SaveAs(
  new FileInfo(@"C:\ExcelTest\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx"))
```

And I want to create this file directly in FTP and NOT locally and then move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make it 2 different operations first one creates the Excel file and then this, uploads existing file and remove it afterward.
Using a library called [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)
I couldn't find any library that supports 90s Encryptions like Implicit FTP over TLS and streaming API at the same time. So there was no way for me to directly create the excel file on the server but to temporary create it locally to copy it over and remove it at the same time, it is almost the same thing I get the same result. And here's solution for doing it

```
try
{
    // Setup session options
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
        HostName = @"xx.xx.x.x",
        UserName = "xxxx",
        Password = "xxxxxx",
        PortNumber = xxxx,
        FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Implicit, //Encryption protocol
        GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnyTlsHostCertificate = true // Accepts any certificate
    };

    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        // Connect
        session.Open(sessionOptions);

        // Upload files
        TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
        transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

        TransferOperationResult transferResult;
        // Copy's Existing file to Connected server and delets the old one.
        // change by replace "true" with "false".
        transferResult =
            session.PutFiles(
                ExistingPath, "/ScheduleJobs/" + RemotePath, true, transferOptions);

        // Throw on any error
        transferResult.Check();

        // Print results
        foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
}
```

Comment: Would you include an explanation, why you needed to use this solution?

Comment: because I couldn't find any library that supports advanced Encryptions like `Implicit FTP over TLS `  so there was no way for me to directly create the excel file on the server but to temporary create it locally to copy it over and remove it, it is almost the same thing I get the same result, but the way I wanted would be "much" better to just create it on server. And here's solution for doing it.

Comment: @leit I know all that, but your answer (not comment) should explain that you had to use this suboptimal solution, only because limitations of your server - *"Implicit FTP over TLS"* is not any *"advanced encryption"* - It's actually a legacy hack from 90s, that no modern FTP server needs to use.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ExcelPackage.SaveAs` overload that accepts a `Stream`](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.1/EPPlus/ExcelPackage.cs#L942-L956) and pass it an FTP request stream, as for example shown in:
[Upload a streamable in-memory document (.docx) to FTP with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47500457/850848)

---

I cannot test EPPlus right now, but this should work:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/sheet.xlsx");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    ExcelPkg.SaveAs(ftpStream);
}
```