# How to upload file to FTP/webdav generated by c# Azure Function?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-functions, azure-storage, webdav

What I'm trying to do, is create an Azure Function that generates certain files.
I then have to:

1. upload these files to an FTP server or Webdav server
2. archive them to a storage account.

What solution do you recommend? How can I store these temp files while I perform the operations above? (Sorry for this n00bish question, this is my first Azure Function that I'm working on.)

Comment: stored them as blobs in a storage container? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Martin-Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help the other community members.

> upload these files to an FTP server or Webdav server

Below is the example code on how to upload `.docx` to FTP server using `memorystream`.
Just copy your stream to the FTP request stream:

```cs
Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
requestStream.Close();
```

For a string (assuming the contents is a text):

```cs
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Or even better use the  `StreamWriter`

```cs
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Write(data);
}
```

If the contents is a text, you should use the text mode:

```
request.UseBinary = false;
```

Check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39226947/15969833) for More Information.

> archive them to a storage account.

Below is the example on how to archive files

```cs
using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\source\directory"))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(path));

            using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
            using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }

    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var request =
        WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/archive.zip");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        memoryStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
    }
}
```

Check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46683554/15969833) for complete information.

Comment: Instead of copying code from the other answers, please consider upvoting them.